# Scanf not taking input character

Tags: c

Here is my code that take count as input and then takes that number of cities as input.
I want to print all the cities starting from that letter but program ends before taking the character as input.
But it doesn't take character input

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{

char a[20][10];
char ch;
int i,n;

printf("Enter nos of cities\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for ( i = 0; i < n ; i++)
{
    scanf("%s",a[i]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("Enter 1st character\n");
scanf("%c", &ch);
for ( i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    if(ch==a[i][0])
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);    


}
```

> OUPUT:

```
Enter nos of cities
3
asd
zxc
qw

Enter 1st character
```

Comment: Thank got the answer

Comment: -1 for not researching the problem. There are TONS of duplicates of this one on SO. In addition to the solution for your problem, (1) Use the standard `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`. (2) Check if `n` is not greater than 20. (3) Limit the input of `scanf` to avoid buffer overruns: `%9s` (4) Check `scanf`'s return value.

Comment: 'line feed in buffer' is the new 'i++ + ++i' :((

Answer (score 5):

Use `scanf(" %c", &ch);`.

The enter from the previous input is taken as input. So add a space before `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line `getchar();` after printing the newline in line 15
Because that `printf("\n")` feeds the `scanf` with a newline character. `getchar()` skips (eats) the newline character here.